# LAN connection not available - wrong driver requested?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi, lan

WiFi works but I cannot see any other devices such as my NAS on the LAN - nor can they see the ubuntu box. My laptop has no problem.

My ubuntu (21.10) box uses Intel WI-FI 6 AX200 (Intel lists required driver as: iwlwifi-cc-46.3... - expands to iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode) but when I "modinfo iwlwifi" it lists iwlwifi-cc-a0-63.ucode to be loaded which is also what is happening ... using "dmesg | grep iwl" it says that the firmware version loaded is iwlwifi-cc-a0-63.ucode ... but also lists an error "api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver". The correct iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode as well as the ...a0-63.ucode files are both in the /lib/firmware directory.
So I guess that I should (somehow?) change the iwlwifi.ko file to request the "cc-46.ucode" version? or ?

Comment: just a small correction ... the ubuntu box can "see" the other devices but cannot access them ""unable to access location" and  "Failed to retrieve share list from server" or "No route to host"

Comment: Such corrections or addendums should be edited in the question.

Comment: “The ubuntu box can "see" the other devices but cannot access them ""unable to access location" and "Failed to retrieve share list from server" or "No route to host" This has nothing to do with the driver or firmware.